# How do you return a new dictionary that only contains a certain type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I specify a new dictionary to only append certain types. For example if my old list was `{'hello': 1, 2:3, 3.0:'hi'}`, how could I make my new list check for the type and then only append that type in it. So `new_dict[int] = {2:3}` or `new_dict[str] = {'hello': 1}`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
d = {'hello': 1, 2:3, 3.0:'hi'}

final_d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, int) and isinstance(k,int)}
```